# Syntax error in for loop (Ruby/RSpec)

Tags: ruby, rspec

While running the RSPEC test as shown below im getting this error:

```
Using Accessor#strict_set for specs
SyntaxError: /home/sam/projects/logstash.king-foo.dev/ansible/roles/logstash/spec/syslog.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected kEND
end
  ^
             load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101
           (root) at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1
             each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
  load_spec_files at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896
  load_spec_files at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896
              run at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22
```

I tried messing around with the syntax but without success.

```
files = Dir['../configs/filter*.conf']
@@configuration = String.new
files.sort.each.do |file|
  @@configuration << File.read(file)
end

describe "my first logstash rspec test", :if => RUBY_ENGINE == "jruby"  do
  extend LogStash::RSpec

  config(@@configuration)
  ... some code here ...
end
```

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?
Why do i get a syntax error for the end statement ander the @@configuration variable?

Comment: Remove the dot between `each` and `do`: `each.do` -> `each do`

Comment: works like a charm! My hero!
Thank you so much! Maybe post as an answer so i can rep you? :)

Comment: I've voted to close the question: there's nothing wrong with it, but it's "a simple typographical error" and "unlikely to help future readers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means there was an unexpected `end` in your code. Just simply replace the 3rd line with

```
files.sort.each do |file|
```

I optionally recommend you use `{` and `}` instead of `do` and `end`. The `{` and `}` are *space-insensitive* and you are less likely to receive an error than `do` and `end`.